# PHP mail function fails to send mail to gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am using mail function to send mail via php script to gmail. Here is the code :

```
if( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))   
    echo "mail sent";
else
    echo "mail not sent";
```

Every time it echos "mail not sent". It fails for gmail but works for other servers.

Any idea why so? Thanks.

Comment: check `spam` folder.

Comment: you run locally or server?

Comment: No sir. It is not in the spam folder.

Comment: @antrooghosh on the server

Comment: Check your mail configuration on server..

Comment: And how to do that?

Comment: No one can guess what happens from what you wrote. First get logs from the php environment and post relevant information. Then people may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with checking the SMTP configration(SMTP stands for simple mail transfer protocol). You can find it in the php.ini; look for the line that reads [mail function]